# How do I host a long-running task on a Windows web hosting?

Tags: iis, web-scraping, windows-services

I'm having a smarterasp.net windows web hosting. I need to have a service that runs permanently and periodically parses a specific remote website, writing results to a log file. I have created a windows servcice, but how do I host it on my web hosting? Running exe files is forbidden, as well as SSH.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: You may ask your hosting provider about this issue. Maybe you need to purchase an addon to execute your job.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have found out, it's often impossible to run a windows service on a web hosting, like in my case. One of the possible workarounds in hosting a background process in the website process, specifically by utilizing things like [hangfire.io](http://hangfire.io)